# winehq package has dependency problem on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Tags: apt, software-installation, wine

I cannot install due to dependency errors

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: winehq-devel: Dependencies: wine-devel (= 2.22.0 ~ xenial)
```

then:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: wine-devel: dependency: wine-devel-amd64 (= 2.22.0 ~ xenial) but it will not be installed depending on: wine-devel-i386 (= 2.22.0 ~ xenial )
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please update your post with output of `apt-cache policy winehq-devel wine-devel`. There are no such packages in Ubuntu repositories or in Wine PPA.

Comment: I did it like https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu  ,so display error,like this question

Comment: and i had do  apt-get remove wine  and  autoremove  ,so now my ubuntu had can't  install wine  ,more and more “rely on” questions.

Comment: and thinks for your translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want install wine2.22:

please remove other wine ppas ,remove all wine ppa，it's old;

then do it:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key`

`sudo apt-key add Release.key`

`sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel`

end,are you ok?

my ubuntu is 16.04.3 64bit,and i with master server；

so the answer to the question is "ppa";

then instell QQ TIM Wechat ;

it's fun!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

- Install wine1.8, first adding i386 archtecture:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install wine1.8
  ```
- If there are dependency issues, use aptitude to resolve them:

  ```
  sudo aptitude --full-resolver -f install wine1.8
  ```

  aptitide will calculate a solution and you should choose the first one
- You may need to downgrade `libcgmanager`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0=0.24-0ubuntu7.5
  ```
- After this, try the installation again:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wine1.8
  ```

Comment: this is wrong ，i had did it ；